# page reload on change event of select box using ajax

Tags: codeigniter-3

ajax function used to reload a content in codeigniter on the change event of select box shows internal server error like Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: More detail is helpful here. Things to look at: 1 - can you access the ajax URL directly? 2 - is there a CI controller setup properly? 3 - are your other pages/routing working?

Comment: Yes i can access the url directly but can't pass the parameter to the controller and access the view page through controller

Comment: public function vendorfilter($category)
{
//$category=$this->input->post('category');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pg_couponcategory');
$this->db->where('cat_id',$category);
$query=$this->db->get();
$slugdata=$query->result_array();
$slug=$slugdata[0]['cat_slug'];

Comment: var category= document.getElementById("categorylist").value; 
            alert(category); 
                        $.ajax({   
                        url: "http://localhost/supersaver/coupons/vendorfilter/"+category,
                        type: "POST", 
                        dataType: "json",                      
                        success: function(msg) {                              
                        alert(msg);    
                        }
     });

Comment: If you add your code to your original question that is better for future reference. It looks ok though but you should try and get it working directly - that would be my start point.